# Why MySQL queries random rows, when selecting only id?

Tags: mysql

I don't understant, why MySQL queries completely random, and unsorted rows, when I'm trying to get only 'id' from table. I won't to use 'ORDER by ...'.

```sql
SELECT `id` FROM `indicator` LIMIT 20;
```

This query returns completely random rows, and unsorted.

If I'll add `name`, to my query, and code will look like:

```sql
SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `indicator` LIMIT 20
```

I will get right sorted elements, which I need.
So, what is that?

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY is kind of meh.

Comment: I tried without LIMIT, result the same, still random rows.

Comment: You request random rows, you get random rows. Since when do you have an aversion to ORDER BY?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not specifying an ORDER BY, MySQL is free to get rows from anywhere it likes, and it will choose the most efficient option. This might be blocks that are in memory or just the start of the table, etc.

When you add the 'name' column, the most efficient option is almost certainly using an index that exists for the 'name' column. Since indexes are always ordered, you get sorted output. If the index were descending, you'd get the last 20 rows, not the first.

You can add an index on the 'id' column (why is it not already there?), but that still doesn't guarantee correct sorting, so it's best to use ORDER BY.

Comment: Can I configure somewhere default ORDER by?

Comment: @Mully How on earth would that work? Default per table, or 'pick the first integer you find in any table', or what?

Comment: Not that I know. It would reduce the efficiency of the database engine by forcing a lot of unneeded sorting operations.

Answer (score 1):

> In the SQL world, order is not an inherent property of a set of data.
>   Thus, you get no guarantees from your RDBMS that your data will come
>   back in a certain order -- or even in a consistent order -- unless you
>   query your data with an ORDER BY clause.

So, to answer your question:

- MySQL sorts the records however it wants without any guarantee of consistency.
- If you intend to rely on this order for anything, **you must specify your desired order using `ORDER BY`. To do anything else is to set yourself up for unwelcome surprises.**

Comment: What is the source of that quote?